# Library for receiving EMail via Android

Tags: java, android, email

Has anyone developed or used an Android library for downloading and sending email (without the use of a UI). I've looked at [javamail-android](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) , but it is GPL. I've also looked at installing [K-9 mail](https://github.com/k9mail) on the phone and configuring the email account, and using the Content Provider to register for incoming emails. The problem with K-9 is that the content provider only includes a summary of the email body text, not the full text.

I'm looking for something that is free and doesn't have a viral license that will enable me to receive email (including the full body text) without using a UI. Or, if anyone knows of a way to to use K-9's content provider to get the full message text, that would be useful. I don't understand why that isn't a parameter you can query for in the content provider. I realize that there are similar questinos out there on SO, but most people answer with "use javamail-android", and I have a feeling most people ignore the GPL license.